# Coverting codes into Array but same output

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, if-statement

i am currently makin a identification quiz using as3, i have a codes here that are actuallyworking through buttons, i just want to ask if its possible to convert my code to array statement but ended up with same output? i really like to make my code an array coz its really flexible, thanks guys

```
   var answer:String = answer.text.toLowerCase();
   if (answer == "allan joshua mccartney" || answer =="mccartney" 
   || answer == "allan" || answer =="joshua" || answer == "joshua mccartney" || answer =="allan joshua" || answer == "allan mccartney") {
score = score +1;
gotoAndStop(2);
```

as you can see my codes is working but it takes really really long codes to finish a single identifcation quiz bcoz there is so many possible answer, i heard that array is the best way to deal with this bunch of possible answers. thans guys

Comment: I think you didn't pass ActionScript tutorials and learnings. my personal advise is http://republicofcode.com.

Comment: I highly recommend you to learn basic things then start making apps.(if you didn't so far)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your answer list:

```
var answersList:Array=new Array("answer1","answer2","answer3");//the list of correct answers
```

Then:

```
var answer:String = answer.text.toLowerCase();
if(answersList.indexOf(answer)>-1){//check if the answer is in the answers list
    score++;// the short form of "score=score +1;
    //the rest of the code
```

**Edit**

to check if the answer contains more than one answer:

use a loop to check items in `answersList`:

```
var numAnswers:uint=0;//number of answers found in the answer.
for(var i:uint=0;i<answerslist.length;i++){
    if(answer.indexOf(answersList[i])>-1){
        numAnswers++;
    }
}
numAnswers;//now this variable contains number of answers found in the answer.
```

of course, it is not so complex and has some problems, for example it answer may contain extra characters that will not be tracked with this code. or some different answers could be part of each other and it won't be tracked. you should do them yourself.

I hope this helps.

Comment: ya sir im sorry im actually new to flash, and this is for my project in school. i will try it sir ill update you soon , thanks

Comment: You're welcome. And I hope you become a master in ActionScript soon.

Comment: Hitman, sir may i ask if i put both answer1 and answer2 for example answe1 is john answer2 is paul and i put john paul. Will still make the answer correct ?

Comment: @JarvisLorenzD.PAlad No in this example, it won't. but in programming, everything is possible. I edited my answer to make it possible.

Comment: wow sir, you are good, i actually admiring you in programming you are so flexible men. thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help you. And I would be more glad if I help you more . so if my answer is the correct answer, you should "accept" my answer by clicking on the green tick on my post.